How to convert an array of strings to union type from an abstract class
I am trying to create a type based on an abstract readonly string[] in an abstract class. When I do so, two things happen:

I get the error 'U' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
The value passed to the column() allows for any type of string

Here is an example in the playground.
What I want to happen, is for the array of strings in MyTable to be converted to a union type for the parameter of the column() method, so that its definition would end up looking like this:
column(name: 'a' | 'b' | 'c');

This is what I have:
export abstract class Table {
  abstract fields: readonly string[];
}

export class MyTable extends Table {
  fields: readonly string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
}

export class ResultSet<T, U extends Table> {
  protected readonly _rows: T[] | T;

  constructor(rows: T[] | T, readonly table: U) {
    this._rows = rows;
  }

  column(name: (typeof U['fields'][number])) {}
}


const set = new ResultSet([], new MyTable());
set.column('123'); // Should throw error


Here,
export class ResultSet<T, U extends Table> 

you're declaring U as a type, then here
U['fields'][number]

you're treating it like a variable. Did you mean to define this._table = table in the constructor, where you've declared table to be a variable of type U, and then use this._table instead of U here?

If I do U['fields'][number], then the parameter of column can be any string, such as cat, where I want only a, b, or c to be able to be passed.
